# ffmpeg - video and audio out of sync

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, sync, video-editing

This seems to be a common problem, but the answers I found don't seem to apply to my situation.

I'm merging 6 videos (one of them is a short background that loops) into 1 output video, and the audio and video are off by a little bit (maybe a quarter second).  Here's my command line:

```
ffmpeg -y
-ss 0.2 -i "One.MOV"
-ss 3.2 -i "Two.MOV"
-i "Three.mp4"
-ss 1.9 -i "Four.mp4"
-ss 1.9 -i "Five.MOV"
-stream_loop 180 -i "Background.mp4"
-filter_complex "
   nullsrc=size=1920x1080 [back];
   [5:v] scale=1920x1080 [fred];
   [back][fred] overlay=shortest=1:x=0:y=0 [base];
   [0:v] crop=1312:1080:290:0,scale=576x474 [clip0];
   [0:a]volume=1.7[aud0];
   [1:v] crop=1080:1056:0:864,scale=497x486 [clip1];
   [1:a]volume=4.8,aresample=async=1:first_pts=0[aud1];
   [2:v] scale=576x324 [clip2];
   [2:a]volume=2.0,aresample=async=1:first_pts=0[aud2];
   [3:v] crop=673:720:322:0,scale=454x486 [clip3];
   [3:a]volume=6.9,aresample=async=1:first_pts=0[aud3];
   [4:v] crop=720:921:0:359,scale=380x486 [clip4];
   [4:a]volume=4.9,aresample=async=1:first_pts=0[aud4];
   [base][clip0] overlay=shortest=1:x=32:y=83 [tmp0];
   [tmp0][clip1] overlay=shortest=1:x=711:y=27 [tmp1];
   [tmp1][clip2] overlay=shortest=1:x=1312:y=158 [tmp2];
   [tmp2][clip3] overlay=shortest=1:x=93:y=567 [tmp3];
   [tmp3][clip4] overlay=shortest=1:x=770:y=567 [tmp4];
   [aud0][aud1][aud2][aud3][aud4]amix=inputs=5[a]
" -map "[tmp4]" -map "[a]" -c:v libx264 "Output.mp4"
```

I'm guessing it has to do with the aresample and first_pts but I've been reading the documentation and can't figure out what I need to do differently.

How can I get my audio and video to synchronize?

EDIT

Note: "Three.mp4" is the piano accompaniment; the other tracks are individual singers, adding their voices to the piano.

Comment: what if you add aresample to [0:a]?

Comment: Alas, setting that filter to "[0:a]volume=1.7,aresample=async=1:first_pts=0[aud0]" didn't change the asynchronicity.

Comment: - _How can I get my audio and video to synchronize?_
- i.e. [audacity](https://www.audacityteam.org/)?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest making a script so that you can include files one by one. to find out which file is faulty.

Create files in new folder, structure is next: test1.mov test1.ss test1.filterv test1.filtera etc.

test1.ss with "0.2"

test1.filterv with "crop=1312:1080:290:0,scale=576x474"

test1.filtera with "volume=1.7"

etc...

```
#!/bin/bash
SUM="$(ls test*.mov test*.mp4 | wc -l)"
echo inputs = $SUM
BOX=1
while [ "$((BOX*BOX))" -lt "$SUM" ]; do ((BOX=BOX+1)); done
echo boxsize = "${BOX}x${BOX}"
WID=640
HEI=360
POX=0
POY=0
INP=()
FCT=-1
FSC=""
FLV=""
FLA=""
AUD=""
BAK="bg"

IFS=$'\n'
for f in $(ls test*.mov test*.mp4); do
  echo $f
  SSI="${f%.*}.ss"
  echo $SSI
  if [[ -f "$SSI" ]]; then
    INP+=("-ss")
    INP+=($(<"${SSI}"))
  fi
  INP+=("-i")
  INP+=("$f")
  ((FCT+=1))

  if [ "$POX" -ge "$BOX" ]; then
    POX=0
    ((POY+=1))
  fi
  ((x=POX*WID))
  ((y=POY*HEI))
  ((POX+=1))

  SSI="${f%.*}.filterv"
  echo $SSI
  if [[ -f "$SSI" ]]; then
    FIL=($(<"${SSI}"))
  else
    FIL=""
  fi

  if [ "$FIL" != "" ]; then
    FSC+="[${FCT}:v:0]${FIL}"
    SC1="${FCT}sca"
    FSC+="[${SC1}]; "
  else
    SC1="${FCT}:v:0"
  fi

  FLV+="[${BAK}][${SC1}]overlay=x=${x}:y=${y}"
  if [ "$FCT" -eq 0 ]; then
    FLV+=":eof_action=endall"
  fi
  BAK="${FCT}v0"
  FLV+="[${BAK}]; "

  SSI="${f%.*}.filtera"
  echo $SSI
  if [[ -f "$SSI" ]]; then
    FIL=$(<"${SSI}")","
  else
    FIL=""
  fi

  FLA+="[${FCT}:a:0]${FIL}aresample=async=1:first_pts=0[${FCT}a0]; "
  AUD+="[${FCT}a0]"
done
((FCT+=1))
((POX=BOX*WID))
((POY=POY*HEI+HEI))
ffmpeg "${INP[@]}" -filter_complex "color=size=${POX}x${POY}[bg]; ${FSC} ${FLV} ${FLA} ${AUD} amix=inputs=${FCT}[a]" -map "[${BAK}]" -map [a] -c:v h264_nvenc -cq 20 -c:a aac -q:a 4 -y output.mkv
```

Add files one by one.

Comment: I created a series of videos, each video is a single singer plus the piano; in every case, the piano is clearly off.  It's much harder to tell with a singer whether the audio matches the video or not, especially if it's only a quarter of a second or so.  So either it's the piano video that's somehow off (although it looks fine when played by itself) or it's my command line that's wrong.

Comment: Your command line is normal. I check your cmdline with films with shooting. Up to 16 movies synced well.

Comment: Hi guys, have you considered possible different driver and frame-per-second encoding issues? @BettyCrokker You should add the encoding parameters of MOV and mp4 files... maybe you can rule out this hypothesis by first trying to convert them all with the same audio / video encoding and next merging them together...

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use some program with a cosy GUI.

This is because you do not seem to be completely sure when your output starts being dissynchronous. A program with a graphical interface, such as [audacity](https://www.audacityteam.org/), should help you solve the issue effectively.

A note on your specific problem:
have you considered possible different driver and frame-per-second encoding issues?
Seldom you can rule out the problem if this is the cause, by first trying to convert them each with the same audio/video encoding (included the frame per second), check for sync and next merging them together...